# Why does a second cin getting skipped over after a while(cin) loop fail?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

This code gets a series of integers using a `while(cin>>x)` loop.

The variable x is pushed back on each iteration to `vector<int> ivec`.

The loops should exit at a non integer input.

After that I want to get one more integer `cin>>y` to check its freq. inside the vector.

**Code:**

```
cout << "Enter a sequence of integers separated with a space: " << flush;
vector<int> ivec;
int x = 0, y = 0;
while( (cin>>x) && (cin.good()) )
{
    ivec.push_back(x);
}

cin.clear();

cout << "Enter an integer to count it's frequency: "<< endl;
cin>>y;

cout << "Y: " <<y<< " X: "<<x << endl;
cout << "Occurred "<< count(ivec.cbegin(), ivec.cend(), y)<< " times."<< endl;

for( int i : ivec)
{
    cout << " "<<i << flush;
}
cout << endl;
```

**Problem:**

When I input a series of integer & the last character is a eof, the while loop gets exited & the second `cin>>y` never executes.
But the rest of the program executes normally. just no more `cin` statements can be executed.

The only case where the second `cin` executes is: if I enter a series of integers separated by a space, press return key, then type the eof (^Z) on a line on its own. I don't know why does it act that way?

**What I've tried:**

I tried `cin.clear()`, it does not resolve the problem.

Also I used `auto stat = cin.rdstate()` before the while loop and `cin.setstate(stat)` after the loop still the second `cin` never executes.

**ScreenShot:**
[image: ScreenShot]

I know `cin` ignores space, tab & newline, so why does a new line make a difference?

I am asking this to how cin works and why its behaving this way. I am aware that I can use getline().

Comment: For 1 2 3 4 ^z after `cin.clear();` you also need to ignore the eof character(use `cin.ignore(1,'eof');`) as `cin.clear();` just clears the error flag on cin and empties the buffer, it doesn't discard the contents but forwards it to y, y doesn't accept it as it's not an integer and prints its initialized value

Comment: It is because of how windows handles end of file in standard input. ^Z is both a character in input and responded to by setting stream state.     So ^Z needs to be followed by newline, and the ^Z remains in the input buffer to be read.    Generally speaking, under windows, it is not a good idea to read from standard input to end of file, even less so if you want to recover from the condition and read more input.    If you really feel you must do that, necessary both to correct the stream state and swallow (read and discard) pending input (e.g. `cin.ignore()`).

Comment: So when cin fails, it does not discard the element, it is left in the istream pending the next input?

Comment: Just a little thing, use `while( (cin.good()) && (cin>>x))` instead.